# Unexpected<hr> line appear when having scrollbar vertically (when height exceed 100%)

Tags: css, reactjs

how the title says the problem is with a line that can be seen in the next image:
[image]

If I remove the table, let's say to not have scrollbar vertically, the line also dissapear:
[image]

What I tried:

- To see If html, body, div root (I use react) use height 100% but not.
- To see with inspect element if that line is a hr or an element that can be removed, it's not
- The only one solution seems to remove padding left-right to override the line or I don't know.

React HTML code:

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <Navbar/>
        <section className="container__ide">
            <div className="container__settings">
                <Tooltip title={'Schimbarea marimii textului pentru editorul text'} placement="left">
                    <Select
                        value={codeFontSize}
                        onChange={handleChangeFontSize}
                        MenuProps={{
                            anchorOrigin: {
                                vertical: "bottom",
                                horizontal: "left"
                            },
                            transformOrigin: {
                                vertical: "top",
                                horizontal: "left"
                            },
                            getContentAnchorEl: null
                        }}
                    >
                        {
                            selectFontSizeOptions.map((fontSize) => {
                                return <MenuItem key={fontSize} value={fontSize}>{fontSize} px</MenuItem>
                            })
                        }
                    </Select>
                </Tooltip>
                <Button>
                    <FaBug/>
                </Button>
            </div>
            <div className="container__problem">
                <div 
                    className="container__statement"
                >
                    <div className="container__top__statement">
                        <span>
                            Descriere
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="container__inner__statement">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div 
                    className="container__code"
                >
                    <div className="container__top__code">
                        <span>
                            Solutie
                        </span>
                        <button>
                            Rulare cod
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="container__inner__code">
                        <Editor
                            height="300px"
                            defaultLanguage="sql"
                            defaultValue="// some comment"
                            theme="my-theme"
                            fontSize="20px"
                            onMount={handleEditorOnMount}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="container__result">
                <MaterialTable
                    columns={[
                        { title: 'Adı', field: 'name' },
                        { title: 'Soyadı', field: 'surname' },
                        { title: 'Doğum Yılı', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
                        { title: 'Doğum Yeri', field: 'birthCity', lookup: { 34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa' } }
                    ]}
                    data={[
                        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 34 },
                        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1988, birthCity: 42 },
                        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1989, birthCity: 63 },
                        { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1989, birthCity: 63 }
                    ]}
                    title="Demo Title"
                    icons={tableIcons}
                />
            </div>
            <div className="container__comments">
                <button>Adauga comentariu</button>
            </div>
        </section>
    </React.Fragment>
)
```

Comment: Hi! Please add a (minimal and runnable) Snippet containing all neccessary code so we can take a look at it.

Comment: @FabianS. done, I added some code.